# Capture the entire contiguous matched input with nom

Tags: rust, parser-combinators

I'm looking to apply a series of [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) parsers and return the complete `&str` that matches. I want to match strings of the form `a+bc+`. Using the existing [`chain!` macro](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/macro.chain!.html) I can get pretty close:

```
named!(aaabccc <&[u8], &str>,
   map_res!(
       chain!(
           a: take_while!(is_a) ~
               tag!("b") ~
               take_while!(is_c) ,
           || {a}
           ),
       from_utf8
   ));
```

where

```
fn is_a(l: u8) -> bool {
   match l {
       b'a' => true,
       _ => false,
   }
}

fn is_c(l: u8) -> bool {
    match l {
        b'c' => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

Say we have 'aaabccc' as input. The above parser will match the input but only 'aaa' will be returned. What I would like to do is return 'aaabccc', the original input.

`chain!` is not the right macro for this, but there was not another that seemed more correct. What would the best way to do this be?

---

At the time of this writing I'm using nom `1.2.2` and rustc `1.9.0-nightly (a1e29daf1 2016-03-25)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears as if you want [`recognized!`](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/macro.recognize!.html):

> if the child parser was successful, return the consumed input as produced value

And an example:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::IResult;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(aaabccc(b"aaabcccddd"), IResult::Done(&b"ddd"[..], "aaabccc"));
}

named!(aaabccc <&[u8], &str>,
   map_res!(
       recognize!(
           chain!(
               take_while!(is_a) ~
               tag!("b") ~
               take_while!(is_c),
               || {}
           )
       ),
       std::str::from_utf8
   )
);

fn is_a(l: u8) -> bool {
   match l {
       b'a' => true,
       _ => false,
   }
}

fn is_c(l: u8) -> bool {
    match l {
        b'c' => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if `chain!` is the best way of combining sequential parsers if you don't care for the values, but it works in this case.

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood `recognize!`. Thank you!

Comment: What if I have `<&str, &str>`, not `<&[u8], &str>`? I get `error: no method named \`offset\` found for type \`&str\` in the current scope`