# Parsing camel case strings with nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I want to parse a string like `"ParseThis"` or `"parseThis"` into a vector of strings like `["Parse", "This"]` or `["parse", "this"]` using the nom crate.

All attempts I've tried do not return the expected result. It's possible that I don't understand yet how to use all the functions in nom.

I tried:

```
named!(camel_case<(&str)>, 
       map_res!(
           take_till!(is_not_uppercase),
           std::str::from_utf8));

named!(p_camel_case<&[u8], Vec<&str>>,
       many0!(camel_case));
```

But `p_camel_case` just returns a `Error(Many0)` for parsing a string that starts with an uppercase letter and for parsing a string that starts with a lowercase letter it returns `Done` but with an empty string as a result.

How can I tell nom that I want to parse the string, separated by uppercase letters (given there can be a first uppercase or lowercase letter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for things that start with any character, followed by a number of non-uppercase letters. As a regex, that would look akin to `.[a-z]*`. Translated directly to nom, that's something like:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::anychar;

fn is_uppercase(a: u8) -> bool { (a as char).is_uppercase() }

named!(char_and_more_char<()>, do_parse!(
    anychar >>
    take_till!(is_uppercase) >>
    ()
));

named!(camel_case<(&str)>, map_res!(recognize!(char_and_more_char), std::str::from_utf8));

named!(p_camel_case<&[u8], Vec<&str>>, many0!(camel_case));

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", p_camel_case(b"helloWorld"));
    // Done([], ["hello", "World"])

    println!("{:?}", p_camel_case(b"HelloWorld"));
    // Done([], ["Hello", "World"])
}
```

Of course, you probably need to be careful about actually matching proper non-ASCII bytes, but you should be able to extend this in a straight-forward manner.

Comment: Thank you that works very good! How long did it take you until you know nom enough to do that in a reasonable amount of time? I'm working on a larger project that requires parsing a lot of strings, for simpler stuff I use nom but still struggle to find my way around, like, i never saw an example of `!recognize` before

Comment: For example: i want to parse a string now first by a function i wrote `parse_camel_case` then for each word parse it by `parse_camel_case`. I am checking the example parsers but nothing seems to what I want do, pipeing the `Vec<&str>` from one parser to another. No idea how to proceed then.

Comment: This is basically why I participate in Stack Overflow ;-) For example, I knew about `recognize!` because [someone asked about it before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36300373/155423). I'm not the biggest fan of nom's documentation (so I wrote my own parser library with **even less** documentation, naturally). Your follow up question should probably be posted as a separate topic as I don't know how to solve it and it's unlikely someone who does will read these comments.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this is what also prevents me creating my "main parser" using nom, I loose too much time trying to find how to use things. So I mainly  use nom for parsing smaller substrings which still seem doable. I will probably create a follow up question, for now I created a regular function that first calls snake case split and then for each item there splits it again for camel case. Works ok for now, but not so pretty code.